# How can I remove string after last underscore in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove the all string after last underscore from the dataframe. If I my data in dataframe looks like.

```
AA_XX,
AAA_BB_XX,
AA_BB_XYX,
AA_A_B_YXX
```

I would like to get this result

```
AA,
AAA_BB,
AA_BB,
AA_A_B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
pd.DataFrame({'col': ['AA_XX', 'AAA_BB_XX', 'AA_BB_XYX', 'AA_A_B_YXX']})['col'].apply(lambda r: '_'.join(r.split('_')[:-1]))
```

Explaination:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['AA_XX', 'AAA_BB_XX', 'AA_BB_XYX', 'AA_A_B_YXX']})
```

Creates

```py
    col
0   AA_XX
1   AAA_BB_XX
2   AA_BB_XYX
3   AA_A_B_YXX
```

Use apply in order to loop through the column you want to edit.
I broke the string at `_` and then joined all parts leaving the last part at `_`

```py
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda r: '_'.join(r.split('_')[:-1]))
print(df)
```

Results:

```py
    col
0   AA
1   AAA_BB
2   AA_BB
3   AA_A_B
```

If your dataset contains values like `AA` (values without underscore).
Change the lambda like this

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['AA_XX', 'AAA_BB_XX', 'AA_BB_XYX', 'AA_A_B_YXX', 'AA']})
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda r: '_'.join(r.split('_')[:-1]) if len(r.split('_')) > 1 else r)
print(df)
```

Comment: The result in the first line of code returns a Series object.  use `df['name']` to edit the column in your existing dataset an explained in explanation. Hope this helps !!

Comment: If `apply` function is taking time, try using `np.vectorize` on `df['name'].values`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this simply using [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`Series.str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
In [2381]: df
Out[2381]: 
         col1
0       AA_XX
1   AAA_BB_XX
2   AA_BB_XYX
3  AA_A_B_YXX

In [2386]: df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.split('_').str[:-1].str.join('_')

In [2387]: df
Out[2387]: 
     col1
0      AA
1  AAA_BB
2   AA_BB
3  AA_A_B
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of going about it.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'s': ['AA_XX', 'AAA_BB_XX', 'AA_BB_XYX', 'AA_A_B_YXX']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def cond1(s):
    temp_s = s.split('_')
    temp_len = len(temp_s)
    if len(temp_s) == 1:
        return temp_s
    else:
        return temp_s[:len(temp_s)-1]
df['result'] = df['s'].apply(cond1)
```